# -cp command in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cp

Copying file from one hdfs location to another using -cp command

Command - `hadoop fs -cp -p /user/cloudera/data/new.txt  /user/cloudera/data1`
(Without creating '`data1`' directory before using above command)

When `-ls` command is used to see the file in the directory `data1`- I do not see the file.

Is it mandatory to create directory and then copy?
As with current case explained above I did not get any error.

Answer (score 1):

`/user/cloudera/data1` is not a directory, it is the file that you copied. That is why there is no error.

If you want a directory containing that file, then yes, you need to `hadoop fs -mkdir`